# Add text at the beginning of each line that follows a condition using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a text at the beginning of each line that is true to a certain condition using Powershell.
for eg; to add "@" at the beginning of each line that has "12345" using powershell

```
Line 12345
Line 23456
Line 12345
```

The output should be

```
@Line 12345
Line 23456
@Line 12345
```

Comment: What do you mean by line? Are these lines of a txt file? Lines of your code? Array elements?

Comment: You could do an if statement if($line = "Line 12345"){ $line = "@" + $line } if you need to loop it then use a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-replace` for this:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '.*12345','@$&' | Set-Content file.txt
```

The first part of `-replace` is the regex string for matching. `.*` is any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`). The second part is the replacement string. `@` is literal. `$&` returns everything that matched.

See [About_Regular_Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7) for more information on regex substitutions with `-replace`.